# Getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'content-length' of undefined When Using Node.js Formidable

Tags: node.js, express, typeerror, ejs, formidable

I'm trying to console.log a number I type in an input using formidable. I am getting an error that says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'content-length' of undefined`. I have tried to add a `fs.readFile` into the code and it won't work.

**Here is my app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const formidable = require('formidable');
const fs = require('fs');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const path = require('path');
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ dest: 'upload/'});
const type = upload.fields([{ name: 'gradeNumber', maxCount: 10 }]);
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');



app.get('/fileupload', function (req, res) {
    res.render("upload")
});
    


app.post('/fileupload', function (req, res) {
    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(function (err, fields, files) {
        console.log(fields.gradeNumber);
        const oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
        const newpath = 'C:/Users/Shubh Computer/Desktop/VSCode/Grades/1/' + files.filetoupload.name;
        fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err; 
            res.write('File uploaded and moved!');
            res.end();
        });
    });
});
app.listen(3000);
```

**upload.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Upload File</title>   
</head>

<body>
    
    <form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>
        
        <label>What Grade</label><input type="text" name="gradeNumber"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
                                                                            
</html>
```

I'm trying to log the input with the name "gradeNumber". If somebody could help me I will be very grateful because I've gotten very frustrated with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"req" parameter in form.parse() method is omitted.

(method) IncomingForm.parse(req: IncomingMessage, callback?: (err: any, fields: Fields, files: Files) => any): void

Try changing the code as below.

```
app.post('/fileupload', function (req, res) {
    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
        console.log(fields.gradeNumber);
        const oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
        const newpath = 'C:/Users/Shubh Computer/Desktop/VSCode/Grades/1/' + files.filetoupload.name;
        fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err; 
            res.write('File uploaded and moved!');
            res.end();
        });
    });
});
```